# Some issues Related to simulation from rLGCP and Point Process Models fitting

Tags: r, field, raster, spatstat

I trying two generate points from `rLGCP` function. I assumed that the presence of these points in the Window is governed by two covaiates `ras1` and `ras2`. Hence I need to comptute log-lambda.

```
rm(list= ls(all=T))
#Libraries
library(spatstat)
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(fields)
```

Creating the domaine D and two rasters

```
D <- c(300, 300)  # Square Domaine D of side 300
Win <- owin(xrange =c(0, D[1]), yrange =c(0,D[2])) 
spatstat.options(npixel=c(D[1],D[2]))

ext <- extent(Win$xrange, Win$yrange) # Extent of the rasters
# First raster ras1
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
ras1 <- raster()
extent(ras1) <- ext
res(ras1) <- 10
names(ras1) <- 'Radiation sim'
crs(ras1) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +datum=WGS84"
values(ras1) <- matrix(c(seq(from =0, to =50, length.out=200), seq(from=50, to=100, length.out = 100), seq(from=100, to=150, length.out = 200), seq(from=150, to=200, length.out = 200), seq(from=200, to=290, length.out = 200)), nrow = 30, ncol = 30)
ras1
plot(ras1, asp=1)

# Second Raster ras2
ras2 <- raster()
extent(ras2) <- ext
res(ras2) <- 10
names(ras2) <- 'Precipitation sim'
crs(ras2) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +datum=WGS84"
values(ras2) <- matrix(c(seq(from =-0, to =200, length.out=500), seq(from=400, to=893, length.out = 20), seq(from=200, to=300, length.out = 300),seq(from=300, to = 400, length.out=80)))
ras2
plot(ras2, asp=1)


Rasters.group <- stack(ras1, ras2)
plot(Rasters.group)
graphics.off()
```

From Rasters to im. objects

```
im.ras1 <- as.im.RasterLayer(ras1); summary(im.ras1)
im.ras2 <- as.im.RasterLayer(ras2); summary(im.ras2)

covar.list <- list(Radiation.sim=im.ras1, Precipitation.sim=im.ras2)

# plot .im object
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
image.plot(list(x=im.ras1$xcol, y=im.ras1$yrow, z=t(im.ras1$v)), main= "Radiation sim", asp=1)
image.plot(list(x=im.ras2$xcol, y=im.ras2$yrow, z=t(im.ras2$v)), main= "Precipitation sim", asp=1)
```

Now I can compute log-Lambda

```
#normalization
norm.im.ras1 <- (im.ras1- summary(im.ras1)$mean)/sd(im.ras1) ; summary(norm.im.ras1)
norm.im.ras2 <- (im.ras2- summary(im.ras2)$mean)/sd(im.ras2) ; summary(norm.im.ras2)

#Compute log-lambda

log.lambda <- norm.im.ras1 + 2*norm.im.ras2
summary(log.lambda)
```

resut dispays very weak values

> Pixel values
> range = [-4.657923, 10.94624]
> integral = -9.678445e-12
> mean = -1.075383e-16

When I try to simulate from rLGCP

```
gen.lgcp <- rLGCP("matern", mu=log.lambda, var=0.5, scale=0.05, nu=1)
```

> Error: could not allocate a vector of size 181.9 MB

I tried to **get around** that with

```
log.lambda0 <- as.im(solutionset(log.lambda>0))
gen.lgcp <- rLGCP("matern", mu=log.lambda0, var=0.5, scale=0.05, nu=1)
summary(gen.lgcp)
```

I can move forward. But further, I did not get relevent results

```
#Thinning
image.plot(list(x=log.lambda$xcol, y=log.lambda$yrow, z=t(log.lambda$v)), main= "log.lambda", asp=1)

samp.lgcp <- rthin(gen.lgcp, P=seq(from=0.02, to=0.2, length.out = gen.lgcp$n));  points(samp.lgcp$x, samp.lgcp$y, type = 'p', cex=0.2, lwd=1, col='white')

#point pattern 
pts.locations <- as.data.frame(cbind(longitude=samp.lgcp$x, latitude=samp.lgcp$y))
ppp.lgcp <- ppp(pts.locations$longitude, pts.locations$latitude, window = owin(xrange=c(min(pts.locations [,1]),max(pts.locations [,1])), yrange = c(min(pts.locations[,2]),max(pts.locations[,2]))))
plot(ppp.lgcp)

#Extract value of each sampled point covariate
cov.value  <- extract(Rasters.group, pts.locations)
cov.value <- as.data.frame(cov.value )
presence.data <- data.frame(pts.locations, cov.value, presence=rep(1, nrow(cov.value)))

### Choosing absence point pattern
abs.region <- crop(Virtual.species.domaine, extent(25.28486 , 162.2897 ,181.7417 , 280.7651 ))
im.abs.region <- as.im.RasterLayer(abs.region)
abs.points <- rasterToPoints(abs.region)
ppp.abs.points <- ppp(abs.points[,1], abs.points[,2], window = owin(xrange = c(min(abs.points[,1]), max(abs.points[,1])), yrange =c(min(abs.points[,2]), max(abs.points[,2]))))
plot(ppp.abs.points)

cov.value.abs <- extract(Rasters.group, abs.points[,1:2])
absence.data <- data.frame(abs.points[,1:2], cov.value.abs, presence=rep(0, nrow(abs.points)))
colnames(absence.data)[1:2] <- c("longitude", "latitude")
head(absence.data)
# Get database for LGCP
LGCP.Data.Set <- rbind(presence.data, absence.data)

#' Model
#' we will use non-stationary formula
covar.formula <- as.formula(paste("~", paste(names(LGCP.Data.Set[,3:4]), collapse = "+")))

#Quadrature scheme
Q.lgcp <- quadscheme(ppp.lgcp, ppp.abs.points, method = 'grid')
plot(Q.lgcp)
```

> Warning message:
> In countingweights(id, areas) :
> some tiles with positive area do not contain any quadrature points: relative error = 94.2%

```
# Inhomogenous poisson process Model
fit.ipp <- ppm(Q.lgcp, trend = covar.formula, covariates = LGCP.Data.Set[,3:4])
summary(fit.ipp)
```

> Warning message:
> glm.fit: algorithm did not converge

**What is going wrong?**

My goal is to evaluate de model and the predict with

```
prediction.ipp <- predict.ppm(fit.ipp, log.lambda, type = 'intensity')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very long and un-focused question but I will try to help.

After constructing the image `log.lambda`, you say "result shows very weak values". What do you mean? The image values were assigned as a sequence of values ranging from 0 to 200, and then standardised to have mean zero and standard deviation 1. How is this "weak"?

You then call `rLGCP` using this image as the mean log intensity. The values of `log.lambda` range from about -4 to +10. This means that the desired intensity will range from `exp(-4)` to `exp(+10)`, that is, about `0.01` to `20 000` points per square unit. The image dimensions are 30 by 30 units. Thus, a very large number of random points must be generated, and this fails because of memory limits. (The expected number of points is `integral(exp(log.lambda))`.

You then change `log.lambda` to another image which takes only the values 0 and 1.

The next body of code appears to take a raster image (of "absence" pixels) and try to construct a quadrature scheme using the "absence" pixels as dummy points. This is not the purpose for which `quadscheme` is designed (for `quadscheme` the dummy points should be sparse).

You don't need to construct a quadrature scheme to use `ppm`. You could just do something like

```
D <- solist(A=im.ras.1, B=im.ras.2)
ppm(ppp.logi ~ A+B , data=D)
```

If you really want to construct a quadrature scheme, I suggest you use the function `pixelquad` instead. Just do `pixelquad(ppp.lgcp, im.abs.region)` or similar. Then use `ppm`.

Since the data were generated by a Cox process, it would be more appropriate to use `kppm` rather than `ppm`.

See [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org) for further information.